# How do you specify default sort direction on particular columns in the Dojo Grid?

Tags: sorting, dojo, grid

I have a dojo grid with a bunch of columns. By default when you click on the column heading, it sorts the column in ascending order (pretty poorly too, giving precedence to capital letters instead of lcas'ing the string in the sort function). What I want is to have the default order be descending when you click the header only for particular columns. For example:

Col A - ascending
Col B - descending
Col C - ascending
Col D - descending

Don't suggest grid.setSortIndex(0) because that only specifies the default sort on the entire grid - that's not what i'm looking for. Dojo documentation is horrible!

Many many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dojox/grid/_Grid#setSortIndex), setSortIndex can receive two parameters - the first for the column index and the second for the direction.

*Note: Edited to have the direct link to the API for that method*

Comment: @OverZealous: How do you get the direct links? I couldn't figure it out when I posted the answer.

Comment: Well, I did it the hard way, but it looks like right-clicking and copying the link from under the *Method Summary* section at the top would work.

Comment: @Overzealous: Just noticed there is a "Permalink" link a the top. >_>

Comment: setSortIndex, as I mentioned, does not do what i'm talking about